# How to delete all screenshots for all sizes and localizations on iTunesConnect?

Tags: app-store-connect

When I uploaded my app, the iTunesConnect website was quite different - I had to upload my screenshots and app preview video just once (for each size), and it automatically appeared for each localisation.

I've improved the graphics, and I'm trying to change the screenshots. To my dismay, it seems that I must click on each screen size (4.7 inch, 5.5 inch etc), and delete each of the screenshots by hand (I wan't to keep the same app preview, so I can't use "delete all"). Worse still, it seems I must do this for each localisation!

That means 4 sizes * 5 screenshots * 30 languages = I have to delete 600 screenshots by hand ???

Worse still - I need to upload those 600 screenshots again ?

Am I missing something really simple ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the quickest way, is to remove all the localisation, and then change only the English (whatever your default language is), then add all the other localisation. This is quicker because you need to upload the pictures just once, but still have to copy / paste the app descriptions etc.